# What is happening in an "If(..||..)" and "If(...&&...)" construct internally?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I was just wondering what happens inside of an "**if OR**" and "**if AND**". I have a feeling that it's just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to use `&&` and `||` and internally all cases are build as single if statements.

Compact form ||:

```
if(a || b || c)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Potential internal form:

```
if(a)
{
    DoSomething();
}    
else if(b)
{
    DoSomething();
}    
else if(c)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

---

Compact form &&:

```
if(a && b && c)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Potential internal form:

```
if(a)
{
    if(b)
    {
        if(c)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any difference in the performance of these two examples?

*Edit: Added the else to the || case

Comment: Why not check if yourself?

Comment: `||` and `&&` are [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) by the way. Also http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Strictly speaking, your interpretation of `||` is wrong - the code you provided will have `DoSomething();` executed three times.

Comment: @SonerGönül What a fantastic link to Mr Lippert, expresses all my frustrations with the unhealthy fixation around performance and C# applications. I will keep hold of that for the next "perf" question I see :-)

Comment: Consider that `a`, `b` and `c` are expensive methods that return a `bool` after a long time. Then it's clear why the short-circuiting operator should be preferred over consecutive `if`s. But even they are not methods but `bool` variables `DoSomething()` gets executed three times instead of one if all are true which is something completely different.

Comment: thx you are right. I haven't realized that DoSomething(); will be executed three times in the case of ||. @SonerGönul: cool link about short-circuit! I didn't know about that

Comment: This question in its general form (it's asked a lot, e.g. "should I use memcpy for structs?") usually comes down to "can I be sure that the language knows how to implement *its own builtin features* in the best way?". Why do you think it would not?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First of all, `||` and `&&` are [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Which mean that in:

```
if(a || b || c)
    DoSomething();
```

if `a` is true, `b` and `c` will not be evaluated.

Secondly, your implementation of the `||` is false:

```
if(a)
    DoSomething();
if(b)
    DoSomething();
if(c)
    DoSomething();
```

`DoSomething()` will be called **up to 3 times**.

It should be:

```
if(a)
    DoSomething();
else if(b)
    DoSomething();
else if(c)
    DoSomething();
```

To finish, if you want *performance* prefer shorter call first in your conditions:

```
if(aShortFunctionToExecute() || aVeryVeryLongFunctionToExecute())
     DoSomething();
```

Will be faster than

```
if(aVeryVeryLongFunctionToExecute() || aShortFunctionToExecute())
     DoSomething();
```

Because of [lazy-evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)

---

If you disassemble the code of:

```
private static void Main()
{
    if (a() && b() && c())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
    }
}
bool a(){
    return true;
}
bool b(){
    return 3 % 2 == 1;
}
bool c(){
    return (3 % 2) / 1 == 1;
}
```

You'll get:

```
    if (a() && b() && c())
00000022  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8D90 
00000027  mov         byte ptr [rbp+20h],al 
0000002a  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+20h] 
0000002e  test        eax,eax 
00000030  je          000000000000005A 
00000032  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8D98 
00000037  mov         byte ptr [rbp+21h],al 
0000003a  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+21h] 
0000003e  test        eax,eax 
00000040  je          000000000000005A 
00000042  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8DA0 
00000047  mov         byte ptr [rbp+22h],al 
0000004a  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rbp+22h] 
0000004e  xor         eax,eax 
00000050  test        ecx,ecx 
00000052  sete        al 
00000055  mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],eax 
00000058  jmp         0000000000000062 
0000005a  nop 
0000005b  mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],1 
00000062  nop 
00000063  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+24h] 
00000067  mov         byte ptr [rbp+2Fh],al 
0000006a  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+2Fh] 
0000006e  test        eax,eax 
00000070  jne         0000000000000087 
        {
00000072  nop 
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
00000073  mov         rcx,12603398h 
0000007d  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx] 
00000080  call        00000000577A82A0 
00000085  nop 
        }
```

and for the code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    if (a())
        if(b())
            if(c())
                Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
}
static bool a(){
    return true;
}
static bool b(){
    return 3 % 2 == 1;
}
static bool c(){
    return (3 % 2) / 1 == 1;
}
```

You'll get:

```
if (a())
00000022  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8D90 
00000027  mov         byte ptr [rbp+20h],al 
0000002a  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rbp+20h] 
0000002e  xor         eax,eax 
00000030  test        ecx,ecx 
00000032  sete        al 
00000035  mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],eax 
00000038  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+24h] 
0000003c  mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Fh],al 
0000003f  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+3Fh] 
00000043  test        eax,eax 
00000045  jne         00000000000000A4 
            if(b())
00000047  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8D98 
0000004c  mov         byte ptr [rbp+28h],al 
0000004f  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rbp+28h] 
00000053  xor         eax,eax 
00000055  test        ecx,ecx 
00000057  sete        al 
0000005a  mov         dword ptr [rbp+2Ch],eax 
0000005d  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+2Ch] 
00000061  mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Fh],al 
00000064  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+3Fh] 
00000068  test        eax,eax 
0000006a  jne         00000000000000A4 
                if(c())
0000006c  call        FFFFFFFFFFEE8DA0 
00000071  mov         byte ptr [rbp+30h],al 
00000074  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rbp+30h] 
00000078  xor         eax,eax 
0000007a  test        ecx,ecx 
0000007c  sete        al 
0000007f  mov         dword ptr [rbp+34h],eax 
00000082  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+34h] 
00000086  mov         byte ptr [rbp+3Fh],al 
00000089  movzx       eax,byte ptr [rbp+3Fh] 
0000008d  test        eax,eax 
0000008f  jne         00000000000000A4 
                    Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
00000091  mov         rcx,125D3398h 
0000009b  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx] 
0000009e  call        00000000577B82A0 
000000a3  nop
```

Which is a bit longer: it takes 40 instructions instead of 31.

---

As pointed out by [thanosqr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730252/thanosqr), the performance also depend of the probability for your condition to be true. To take his example:

If `a` fails 99% of the time and take 1 sec to run and if `b`
 succeed 99% of the time and take 10 sec to run, over 100 tries you'll be faster putting `b` first:

```
if(b || a) => 10s 99% ==> 100 runs will take 99*10+11 = 1001s
if(b || a) => 11s 1%

if(a || b) => 11s 99% ==> 100 runs will take 99*11+1 = 1090s
if(a || b) => 1s 1%
```

Also, I suggest you this reading " [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) " which is quite interesting!

Comment: "It's 25% faster to use the compact way." No, it's not. It takes 25% less instructions. The number of instructions is no indication of how fast it will run, and it will vary wildly depending on many many different parameters.

Comment: I would say that performance also depends on chance of short-circuiting; e.g.: if the fast check takes 1sec and fails 99 times out of 100 while the slow check takes 10sec but fails only 1 time, (slow || fast) would take 1001sec while (fast || slow) would take 1090 sec. the extreme case would be a check that's always false, even if it's super fast it's better to check the slow one first.

Comment: Please clarify definition of "IL".

Comment: @Thomas Intermediate language? MSIL? Please look at the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Using the compact form, the IL emitted by the C# compiler will be less verbose, resulting in less instructions to be handled at runtime. The emitted IL statements and their logic are actually the same, so there's no fancy built-in support to handle that case or some special instruction (keep in mind that you can put *any* expression with a boolean result into an `if`).

For the compact form using the `||` operator (debug build):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  One() cil managed
{
  // Code size       38 (0x26)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::a
  IL_0006:  brtrue.s   IL_0019
  IL_0008:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::b
  IL_000d:  brtrue.s   IL_0019
  IL_000f:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::c
  IL_0014:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0015:  ceq
  IL_0017:  br.s       IL_001a
  IL_0019:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001a:  nop
  IL_001b:  stloc.0
  IL_001c:  ldloc.0
  IL_001d:  brtrue.s   IL_0025
  IL_001f:  call       void ConsoleApplication4.Program::DoSomething()
  IL_0024:  nop
  IL_0025:  ret
} // end of method Program::One
```

With your internal form (considering you're using `else if` instead of an `if`):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Two() cil managed
{
  // Code size       60 (0x3c)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::a
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0007:  ceq
  IL_0009:  stloc.0
  IL_000a:  ldloc.0
  IL_000b:  brtrue.s   IL_0015
  IL_000d:  call       void ConsoleApplication4.Program::DoSomething()
  IL_0012:  nop
  IL_0013:  br.s       IL_003b
  IL_0015:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::b
  IL_001a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001b:  ceq
  IL_001d:  stloc.0
  IL_001e:  ldloc.0
  IL_001f:  brtrue.s   IL_0029
  IL_0021:  call       void ConsoleApplication4.Program::DoSomething()
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  br.s       IL_003b
  IL_0029:  ldsfld     bool ConsoleApplication4.Program::c
  IL_002e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_002f:  ceq
  IL_0031:  stloc.0
  IL_0032:  ldloc.0
  IL_0033:  brtrue.s   IL_003b
  IL_0035:  call       void ConsoleApplication4.Program::DoSomething()
  IL_003a:  nop
  IL_003b:  ret
} // end of method Program::Two
```

So there are way more instructions to handle all the jumps required by the additional `if` statements. The first form is therefore more efficient (and actually more readable :)).

In terms of performance (each method measured 10 times with 10.000.000 iterations and removed the highest and lowest values, release build):

Compact form: 55ms in average

Verbose form: 56ms in average

So there's no big difference at all.

Comment: @Gene, faster, isn't it ? :)

Answer (score 3):

For those who read C# better than assembly, the real internal forms are closer to:

```
if(a) goto yes;
if(b) goto yes;
if(c) goto yes;
goto no;
yes:  DoSomething();
goto done;
no:   /* if there were an else it would go here */;
done: ;
```

for

```
if(a || b || c)
  DoSomething();
```

and

```
if(!a) goto no;
if(!b) goto no;
if(!c) goto no;
yes:  DoSomething();
goto done;
no:   /* if there were an else it would go here */;
done: ;
```

for

```
if(a && b && c)
  DoSomething();
```

That's because the actual instructions are conditional branches -- in the internal form it is not possible for an `if` to be associated with a block, a nested `if`, or actually anything except a `goto`.

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
if(a)
    if(b)
        if(c)
            DoSomething();
```

is a logical (but not "practical") equivalent for:

```
if(a && b && c)
    DoSomething();
```

As for the `OR` operator you've got it a bit wrong. A logical (but, again, not "practical") equivalent for:

```
if(a || b || c)
    DoSomething();
```

would be:

```
if(a)
    DoSomething();
else if(b)
    DoSomething();
else if(c)
    DoSomething();
```

By practical difference I understand any resulting code differences introduced by the compiler (refer to other answers for details).

Answer (score 2):

[`||`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx) and [`&&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) are conditional-operators. They're also operators, like other operators you might know. (e.g. `+`, `*`, ...)

Their behavior is similar to logical-operators, `|` and `&`. They receive two `bool` type variables and return `bool` value in this way:

```
// If one of them is true, the return value is true. Otherwise, it's false.
true  | true  == true
true  | false == true
false | true  == true
false | false == false
// If both of them are true, the return value is true. Otherwise, it's false.
true  & true  == true
true  & false == false
false & true  == false
false & false == false
```

However, as for conditional-operators, there's a bit difference: **short-circuit**.

Suppose this code:

```
bool func1() { .. }
bool func2() { .. }

bool b1 = func1() || func2();
bool b2 = func1() && func2();
```

If `func1()` returns `true`, `b1` becomes `true` regardless of what `func2()` returns. Therefore, we don't need to call `func2()` and actually don't. If `func1()` returns `false`, the same thing is applied to `b2`. This behavior is called short-circuit.

---

Now, let's think about your example.

```
if (a || b || c)
    DoSomething();
```

It's equal to

```
bool value = a || b || c;
if (value)
    DoSomething();
```

Since the [order of evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) of conditional operators is left-to-right, it's equal to

```
bool value = (a || b) || c;
if (value)
    DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

Their VB equivalents can be more describing. `||` is `OrElse` and `&&` is `AndAlso` in VB.
These are conditional operators; meaning they make the control clause - `if` in your case - evaluate the conditions as needed and not all of them always.

For example, in `if ( a || b )` if `a` is true, it doesn't matter what `b` is; the result is true and therefore `b` will not get evaluated and this will result in faster execution.

This feature can be used as a null-checking mechanism too. `if ( a != null && a.prop == somevalue )` will prevent a Null Reference Exception if `a` is null and if it's not null, its `prop` property will be accessed to evaluate the second condition.