# Effect of the ||-operator on ++x

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=0, k=0, m;
   m = ++i || ++k;
   printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, k, m);
   return 0;
 }
```

returns

```
1,0,1
```

Why is k = 0 and not 1? what is the effect of the ||-operator on the ++k?
Thanks!

example: https://ideone.com/Fjsbii

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Or [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29141619/2307070)

Comment: possible duplicate of [If Statements - What is happening in an "If(..||..)" and "If(...&&...)" construct internally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141368/if-statements-what-is-happening-in-an-if-and-if-construc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `||` OR ,  if first condition is true, it will not check second condition.(it will skip 2nd condition).

As

```
m = ++i || ++k;
```

in this condition after `++i`, value of `i` will become `1`, as first condition is `true`, so it will skip second condition. so the operation `++k` will not be performed.
And hence `k` will remain `0`.

Same as if you are using  `&&` , and first condition is `false` it will skip second condition. and result will be `0` (false).

Comment: Mention the word "short-circuit" somewhere.