# In Python why is "'a' and 'b' and 'c'" is 'c', and "'a' or 'b' or 'c'" is 'a'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any logic behind it?

```
>>>'a' and 'b' and 'c'
'c'
>>>'a' or 'b' or 'c'
'a'
```

Comment: I recommend you a [bit of reading about laziness in IT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29141619/2307070)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is logic, Boolean logic.

Boolean operators in Python are lazy, so they return the first value that proves that the entire statement is True.

`'a' and 'b' and 'c'` returns `c` because it's the first time it can prove the whole statement is True.

`'a' or 'b' or 'c'` returns `a` because it's True, so the rest of the values in the statement don't matter.